# Is there any way to take my current setup and put it on a live disk, then install it to another machine?

Tags: backup, installation, cd-image

A tutorial or specific directions would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot :)! (just kidding).

There is [remastersys](http://remastersys.sourceforge.net/). It is highly documented, so I won't bother to re-document it here ^^!
Here is a link: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html

Keep in mind this only keeps the software you have installed plus a few other bits and pieces. To get your home folder etc copied, you will need to manual transfer that data yourself, the instructions for which would be better off in another question/answer couple.

Most of your settings will not be transfered automatically, except for what it stored in the system wide configuration. This is a limitation of the scripts used to create the live environment.

To counter this, you can copy your themes and icons to `/usr/share/themes` and `/usr/share/icons` respectively, as well as set the gconf entries for your gtk/icon/metacity themes using gconf-editor to default (sorry I could not capture the menu in my screenshot). *(right click the entry, then click set as default)*

[image]

A more extensive option (sorry I could not find one of the the links I was looking for) is to create/customize a live cd (as according to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) guide).

After installing this system, you could "make it like your existing system" using a few commands.

The steps to this are described in detail [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/clone-your-ubuntu-installation.html).

No matter what method you choose, always consider carefully, before attempting such an operation, and wherever possible, try to backup your critical data.

Comment: So the setting won't go with it? like themes, backgrounds other various changes I may have made?

Comment: nope. Not unless you set these to be the defaults in gconf, which is a little more complicated. If you like I can add this to my answer.

Comment: yes please do..